# Error compilando .pyw a exe con py2exe

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando compilar un fichero .pyw a .exe con py2exe el setup.pyw contiene lo siguiente:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['laZagne.pyw'],options={'py2exe': { 
"dll_excludes": ["MSVFW32.dll",
                 "AVIFIL32.dll",
                 "AVICAP32.dll",
                 "ADVAPI32.dll",
                 "CRYPT32.dll",
                 "WLDAP32.dll"]
}})
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll'

Alguien sabe el motivo o la solucion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene un error o falta dicha `DLL` puede intentar instalando la [Actualización](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/2999226)
o ejecutando el comando `sfc /scannow` desde la consola como Administrador.

Comment: la pagina de soporte técnico me sale Intenta buscar lo que necesitas

Esta página no existe.

Comment: Verificar nuevamente.

Comment: esto esta solucionado pero ahora tengo otro error que hare publico